# Initialize interop Excel app on the background

Tags: asp.net-mvc, initialization, interop, office-interop, com-interop

I am developing a ASPNET web app which uses interop for different tasks. In order to make the app faster I was wondering if I can run Excel on the background while the view is loading. I tried the following approach:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SVUsr.png)

However, every time you go into the view the app is initializated so you have the app running many times in the background. Is there a way of doing it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft does not currently recommend, and does not support, Automation of Microsoft Office applications from any unattended, non-interactive client application or component (including ASP, ASP.NET, DCOM, and NT Services), because Office may exhibit unstable behavior and/or deadlock when Office is run in this environment.

If you are building a solution that runs in a server-side context, you should try to use components that have been made safe for unattended execution. Or, you should try to find alternatives that allow at least part of the code to run client-side. If you use an Office application from a server-side solution, the application will lack many of the necessary capabilities to run successfully. Additionally, you will be taking risks with the stability of your overall solution. Read more about that in the [Considerations for server-side Automation of Office](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/considerations-for-server-side-automation-of-office-48bcfe93-8a89-47f1-0bce-017433ad79e2) article.

As a workaround, you may consider using the [Open XML SDK](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/open-xml/open-xml-sdk) for open XML documents or third-party components designed for the server-side execution.